# In SwiftUI, how to implement @Published class in the right way

Tags: swiftui, observableobject

In SwiftUI, I have a class for user data and I convert JSON data into it:

```
class UserData: Codable {
    var displayName: String
    var employeeId: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    // more ...
}
```

by `JSONDecoder().decode(UserData.self, from: jsonData)`

And I have a class UserProfile holding the user data:

```
class UserProfile : ObservableObject {
  
    @Published var userData: UserData?

}
```

Now the problem is that, whenever I updated userData, like

`userProfile.userData?.displayName = "New John"`

the data change is not published to the view. I know the reason is because the userData is actually a class, so if I do

`userProfile.userData = userProfile.userData` after a value is newly assigned, the view gets updated.

My question is how to do it in the right way? I don't want to call `userData = userData` each time a value is updated, it doesn't sound right.

Comment: Any reason you can’t make UserData a struct?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez would struct solve the problem?

Comment: Struct is the easiest answer here

Comment: @BenzyNeez You can't have Codable & ObservableObject at the same time for a class.

Comment: Since struct works, why not make it an answer with explanations.

Comment: @JoeHuang I deleted my earlier comment to avoid adding confusion. My full answer can be found below, it would work for a struct too (except you would need to use ```var``` instead of ```let```).

Comment: @JoeHuang posted my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make `UserData` a `struct`, any changes to its properties will be published like you want.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT: updated to use* `objectWillChange.send()` *as suggested by the observers...*

So `UserProfile` is a wrapper for `UserData` to allow changes to the underlying data to be observed. What you can do is provide getters/setters in the wrapper class for the underlying properties. Whenever a property is updated via a setter, the wrapper class notifies its observers by calling `objectWillSend.send()`.

If you can avoid the optional then it would look something like this:

```swift
class UserProfile : ObservableObject {

    private let userData: UserData

    init(userData: UserData) {
        self.userData = userData
    }

    var displayName: String {
        get { userData.displayName }
        set {

            // Notify observers before applying the change
            objectWillChange.send()

            userData.displayName = newValue
        }
    }

    // etc.
}
```

If you can't avoid the optional then of course the getters/setters would have to handle it appropriately, for example:

```swift
    var displayName: String {
        get { userData?.displayName ?? "" }
        set {
            if let userData {
                objectWillChange.send()
                userData.displayName = newValue
            }
        }
    }
```

This approach gives you full control over which properties of the underlying instance can be mutated. For example, you might not want to allow `employeeId` to be mutated. You could also make sure that properties which belong together can only be updated together, for example `firstName` and `lastName`.

If you wanted to, you could still keep `userData` as a published property and let it be swapped out with a new instance.

Comment: Calling objectWillChange.send() is a much simpler version of this